# Boolean circuit - 4 inputs (A, B, C, D), and output Z performs the function: Z =1 for all numbers divisible by 3

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates

I need to draw a circuit using the minterm, with 4 inputs (A, B, C, D) and an output (Z) that performs the function: Z =1 for all numbers divisible by 3, in Xilinx ISE with only using Schematic without VHDL.

I first thought to draw truth table which I would use for Karnaugh Map.  When I get the function and draw circuit on paper, do I just copy circuit to Xilinx ISE, or do I need to do something else. What even is the correct minimized function and circuit for this problem.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: For homework questions we expect to see that you have made a substantial effort to solve the problem yourself. Show us all of your work, then ask a **specific** question.

Answer (score 1):

1 = 1 (mod 3)
2 = -1 (mod 3)
4 = 1 (mod 3)
8 = -1 (mod 3)

You're looking for numbers that are equal to 0 (mod 3), which means they have an equal number of "1" and "-1" bits set. Does that help?

Answer (score -1):

**(1)** Numbers divisable by 3

As you have four input bits, you can represent the numbers `0-15`.

Therefore, `Z=1 for (A-D)=3,6,9,12,15`

**(2)** Binary representation of these numbers

You now need to map the Vector `(A-D)` with the selected numbers into binary:

- `3 = 0011`
- `6 = 0110`
- `9 = 1001`
- `12 = 1100`
- `15 = 1111`

**(3)** Reduction of the Terms

You now have your logic table at hand.

- `Z=1` for the cases above
- `Z=0` for all other cases

You now need to reduce this to the minimal viable function by .e.g a [Wiki KV-Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

**(4)** Drawing the Term

You now can Draw the Term for Z(A,B,C,D) in Xilinx ISE via common logic Gates (AND, OR) or (NAND, NOR).

E.g : `Z(A,B,C,D)= Av(BC)vD` results in (B-*AND*-C)-*OR*-A-*OR*-D

Comment: There is one number missing from your lists.